# Swift Firebase - trying to retrieve more than one set of data in a function to count the number of entries

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem trying to retrieve two sets of data from Firebase, in one function. The results from this retrieve will be used to update a progress bar, after the retrieve (otherwise 'zero' values) so this 'progress bar' function is also included in the Firebase function. To clarify further, I am trying to get the count of entries for 'user-posts', and 'user-plans' from the Firebase Db:-
[image]

[image]

The code for the function looks like this (and then I'll let you know what the issue is!):-

```
func firebaseRetrieve() {

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}

    let planRef = DB_BASE.child("user-plan").child(uid)
    planRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.key
            self.totalPlans.append(key)
            self.planCount = Double(self.totalPlans.count)

            let postRef = DB_BASE.child("user-posts").child(uid)
            postRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                for child in snapshot.children {
                    let snaps = child as! DataSnapshot
                    let keys = snaps.key
                    self.totalPosts.append(keys)
                    self.postCount = Double(self.totalPosts.count)

                    self.fraction = self.postCount / self.planCount

                    //THIS IS WHERE I INPUT ANOTHER FUNCTION TO PASS THE VALUE OF 'FRACTION' INTO, THAT THNE DETERMINES THE PROGRESS BAR
                }
            })
        }
    })
```

THE ISSUE: The current count of 'user-plan' is 18. The current count of 'user-posts' is 14. So the fraction should equal 0.77 (78%). But, the count of 'user-posts' seems to be reiterated 18 times, so the count is 252 (i.e. 14 * 18)!! I've tried all sorts to fix it over the past 3 days, but always the same result.
Any ideas greatly received, and will stop me swearing at the wife......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`snapshot.childrenCount`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#childrencount) to get the count of the snapshot children , and you need to move your calculation for fraction outside the loop

checkout this code

```
func firebaseRetrieve() 
{

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}

    let planRef = DB_BASE.child("user-plan").child(uid)
    planRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: 
    { 
        (snapshot) in

        self.planCount = snapshot.childrenCount;
        for child in snapshot.children 
        {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.key
            self.totalPlans.append(key)
        }


        let postRef = DB_BASE.child("user-posts").child(uid)
        postRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: 
        { 
            (snapshot) in

            self.postCount = snapshot.childrenCount;
            for child in snapshot.children 
            {
                let snaps = child as! DataSnapshot
                let keys = snaps.key
                self.totalPosts.append(keys)
            }

            self.fraction = self.postCount / self.planCount;
            print("fraction = \(self.fraction)")

        })

    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ali - that very nearly works! I left out the 'self.postCount = snapshot.childrencount;' as there was an 'assigning' value error, but that's ok, I am now getting the correct values for the plan and post counts. However, the 'self.fraction' is returning a 'nan'. Any idea why?

Comment: check the edit I add new line after fraction calculation , what to get in your console ?

Comment: I printed out all the values, to see if the total posts and plan counts were getting through - and they were - results in the console were: Plan Count = 18, Post Count = 14, but Fraction = nan....

Comment: actually I have no idea , you can post more code to see if there a problem

Comment: Just figured it out - I needed to cast the post and plan counts as Doubles before I did the fraction calculation. Thanks for your help @Ali - wouldn't have got there without it!

Comment: happy to help you :)